# In PHP, how to print a string that contains HTML to a web browser as a string?

Tags: php, html

(1) I try to compose some HTML in my PHP code and want to print it as a string, for example if I have code like this

```
$html_content = '<div style="..."> hi, this is a test </div>';
```

How to output this $html_content so that from the web browser, I can see something as what $html_content string contains? I want to check if the string content is correct or not. I am not generating some HTML page.

(2) While I am doing this, following code kind of confuses me

```
$html_content = 'aaa';
output("1:".$html_content);
$html_content += '<div class="myclass">';
output("2:".$html_content);
```

the output is

```
1:aaa2:0
```

why is it "0" in this case?

Comment: `+` is the *addition operator*, strings are concatenated with `.`.

Comment: `+` is numeric addition in PHP. To concatenate strings, you must use the `.` operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't believe I made this obvious mistake :) I was using javascript for a long time, so it was kind of straight forward to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of **`htmlentities`** to display the HTML content.

```
<?php
$html_content = '<div style="..."> hi, this is a test </div>';
echo htmlentities($html_content);
```

Also , you are concatenating it wrongly , use **`.`** instead of **`+`**

```
<?php
$html_content = 'aaa';
echo("1:".$html_content);
$html_content .= '<div class="myclass">';
echo("2:".$html_content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shankar already answered your first part of the question. As for part (2), + and += are arithmetic operators; therefore, if you write something such as 'a'+'b', the two strings will first be transformed into numbers, becoming zero, and then added together the result 0.

To concatenate strings, use . instead of +. If you meant to concatenate '' to the string $html_content, you should have used the operator .= instead of +=